# Chromecast ios api.. Entity not found

Tags: ios, chromecast

Anyone encountered this already?. I downloaded the sample code for IOS from github. I replaced the app id with my own, that i got after whitelisting my device. I ran the app and selected the device and media to cast. Soon after I hit the cast button, I am getting the following error....

Failed to start application (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError); caused by: entity not found (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKNetworkRequestError).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution for this one. Once I enabled the Chromecast to send it's serial number to Google, the error went away (for future reference). It can be done in settings.

Source: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-demo-player/issues/5